# Why the number of calls generated by LINQ FirstOrDefault or First

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've noticed some performance issues with our application and have tracked it down to sheer number of calls to ID properties on our classes.

I've set up a sample to explain.

We have two classes, Person and Address.

I take and create 10 instances of each, all having ID fields (Person_Id, Address_Id).

In the case of this sample, Person_Id of 1 maps to Address_Id of 1.

In order to link these together I have a read-only property in Person of 'Address' and it returns the associated address object by performing a LINQ query against the collection of addresses.
**For simplicity I'm returning addresses where the Address_Id = the Person_Id since I have an equal # of items in each list and this is for testing.**

```
public Address Address
{
    get
    {
        return Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Address_Id == Person_Id);
    }
}
```

Person_Id is a public property with a private backing field. Very simple.

```
private int _person_Id;
public int Person_Id 
{
    get
    {
        return _person_Id;
    }
    set
    {
        _person_Id = value;
    }
}
```

When tracking the number of times the get inside of Person_Id is called, the amount is always higher than the number of person records. In this case I'm iterating the list of person records and outputting the name and state of the person.

```
foreach (var person in persons)
{
   var name = person.Name;
   var state = person.Address.State;
   Console.WriteLine(name + "\t" + state);
}
```

Here is how the number of calls break down based on the number of person entities iterated:

[image: calls based on # of records]

Reviewing the math, we can see that adding the # of address calls for the current entity we are on and **above** adds to the total calls for Person_Id. For example: If we have 5 person records iterated, there are 5 calls to the get of the 'Address' property of person and 15 calls to the get of the 'Person_Id' property of person. 15 is (5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1), the summation of the calls to 'Address.'

I am curious where these numbers are coming from. It is the same for *FirstOrDefault* and *Find*. If I use *Single* the calls are much higher.

If I instead create a local variable such as this:

```
int personId = Person_Id;
```

And then use it in the LINQ query:

```
return Addresses.Find(a => a.Address_Id == personId);
```

Then the calls are a 1 to 1 -- I have 1 call to Address and Person_Id as I would have expected from the LINQ query.

Does anyone know why the calls are inflated in this way? I'm interested to learn more as I go through the process of optimizing.

Thanks

Comment: You have issues with the way your classes are linked. you should create a private address in the person class and when you call the property check if the private variable is null and if it is set it to the id of address you are looking for. If the private isn't null return it right away. You are currently looping for each individual property you are calling on `Person.Address`

Comment: Why do you ask number of calls generated by FirstOrDefault when you have not even tested FirstOrDefault.  Why not test youself?   LINQ is still making multiple calls to personID - you have optimized nothing.

Comment: I should add that using Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Address_Id == Person_Id) and return Addresses.Find(a => a.Address_Id == Person_Id) yield the same number of calls to Person_Id. I left the sample code in the initial post where I'd been getting the #s for 'Find' and have updated it to 'FirstOrDefault' to clear up any confusion that may present. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You're basically saying "for each address within `Addresses`, evaluate this predicate, until the predicate returns `true`, at which point return that address."

The predicate is the lambda expression, which uses the `Person_Id` property, so it has to evaluate it every time.

Or to put it another way, suppose you used a normal method instead of a lambda expression in order to create the predicate:

```
public Address Address
{
    get
    {
        Predicate<Address> predicate = new Predicate<Address>(AddressIdMatches);
        return Addresses.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }
}

private boolean AddressIdMatches(Address a)
{
    return a.Address_Id == Person_Id;
}
```

Is that clearer? The method will be called once per address, and it's hopefully obvious that every time you call that method, it's going to evaluate `Person_Id`. That's what the compiler is basically building for you when you use the lambda expression.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed when you mentioned it that I left the 'Find' in there from testing and updated it back to 'FirstOrDefault' -- I was testing them both to see the difference.

Comment: @dunderwood: Okay, I've removed the introductory part.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the question, this lambda expression:

```
a => a.Address_Id == Person_Id
```

Is really equivalent to this lambda expression:

```
a => a.Address_Id == this.Person_Id
```

You are implicitly capturing `this` in the lambda - not the value of `this.Person_Id`.  So the `Person_Id` property getter is called repeatedly for each `Address` `a` that is checked.

If you change the code to this:

```
int personId = Person_Id;
...
a => a.Address_Id == personId
```

Then you are capturing the variable `personId` instead, which does not need to call the `Person_Id` property getter each time it is read.